# Exception on running game with proton

Tags: permissions, steam

I got Ubuntu 18.04, I installed newest version of Steam, then I get Proton.
When I'm trying to run game Call to Arms, there's EXCEPTIO_ACCESS_VIOLATION:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/458St.png)

Any idea why it's happen? It looks like problem with rigths (steam & game is in my home dir). I was thinking about running steam with sudo, but I read on internet that it could crash system.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run steam as root, there is no benefit. 
You can search protondb for the game, there are some results. Some can run it, some not. Seems related to grafic driver, which you forgot to tell us.
The error message you posted above are register messages from the cpu i think, nothing about permission. Take a look to the crash log.

Comment: I got GTX 1050 ti & driver 415.27 i installed it, because it's newest driver for nvidia cards, but I'm not sure if it's proper driver for my card. Now game is launching only in safe mode.